# MongoDb concat string into existiing field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document:

```
 {
  "_id":"000001"
  "publicId":"0001"
  "name":John"
 }
```

Now i would like to concat "M" before each publicId. I did query like this:

```
db.names.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { publicId: { $concat: [ "M", "$publicId" ] } }},
      {$out:"names"}
   ]
)
```

The problem I have is that I lose the name property:

```
 {
  "_id":"000001"
  "publicId":"M0001"
 }
```

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Use `{ $project: { name:1, publicId: { $concat: [ "M", "$publicId" ] } }}` in 3.2 and `{ $addFields: { publicId: { $concat: [ "M", "$publicId" ] } }}` in 3.4.

Comment: Thanks, the 3.2 Version worked for me